# replace every occurrence of 'line 2' with line_2 with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm parsing some text from an XML file which has sentences like
"Subtract line 4 from line 1.", "Enter the amount from line 5"
i want to replace all occurrences of line  with line_
eg. Subtract line 4 from line 1 --> Subtract line_4 from line_1

Also, there are sentences like "Are the amounts on lines 4 and 8 the same?" and "Skip lines 9 through 12; go to line 13."
I want to process these sentences to become
"Are the amounts on line_4 and line_8 the same?"
and
"Skip line_9 through line_12; go to line_13."

Comment: Are all the numbers in your XML about lines ?

Comment: mostly...its a tax instruction file issued by the IRS

Comment: Would there be a "Are the amounts on lines 4, 5 and 6 the same?" You get the point ?

Comment: just today i've come across a few lines in my xmls as "Enter the total of the amounts from Form 1040A, lines 7, 8a, 9a, 10, 11b, 12b, and 13" and "Add lines 2, 3, and 4"

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working implementation with rspec test. You call it like this: `output = LineIdentifier[input]`. To test, `spec file.rb` after installing rspec gem.

```
require 'spec'

class LineIdentifier
  def self.[](input)
    output = input.gsub /line (\d+)/, 'line_\1'
    output.gsub /lines (\d+) (and|from|through) (line )?(\d+)/, 'line_\1 \2 line_\4'
  end
end

describe "LineIdentifier" do
  it "should identify line mentions" do
    examples = { 
      #Input                                         Output
     'Subtract line 4 from line 1.'               => 'Subtract line_4 from line_1.',
     'Enter the amount from line 5'               => 'Enter the amount from line_5',
     'Subtract line 4 from line 1'                => 'Subtract line_4 from line_1',
    }
    examples.each do |input, output|
      LineIdentifier[input].should == output
    end
  end
  it "should identify line ranges" do
    examples = { 
      #Input                                         Output
     'Are the amounts on lines 4 and 8 the same?' => 'Are the amounts on line_4 and line_8 the same?',
     'Skip lines 9 through 12; go to line 13.'    => 'Skip line_9 through line_12; go to line_13.',
    }
    examples.each do |input, output|
      LineIdentifier[input].should == output
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Mark, i've come across a few lines in my xmls as 
"Enter the total of the amounts from Form 1040A, lines 7, 8a, 9a, 10, 11b, 12b, and 13"
and
"Add lines 2, 3, and 4"

How should i deal with these?

Comment: i have come as far as using (\d+\w?) for the line numbers

Answer (score 0):

This works for the specific examples including the ones in the OP comments.  As is often the case when using regex to do parsing, it becomes a hodge-podge of additional cases and tests to handle ever-increasing known inputs.  This handles the lists of line numbers using a while loop with a non-greedy match.  As written, it is simply processing an input line-by-line.  To get series of line numbers across line boundaries, it would need to be changed to process it as one chunk with matching across lines.

```
open( ARGV[0], "r" ) do |file|
  while ( line = file.gets )
    # replace both "line ddd" and "lines ddd" with line_ddd 
    line.gsub!( /(lines?\s)(\d+)/, 'line_\2' )
    # Now replace the known sequences with a non-greedy match
    while line.gsub!( /(line_\d+[a-z]?,?)(\sand\s|\sthrough\s|,\s)(\d+)/, '\1\2line_\3' )
    end
    puts line
  end
end
```

**Sample Data**: For this input:

```
Subtract line 4 from line 1.
Enter the amount from line 5
on lines 4 and 8 the same?
Skip lines 9 through 12; go to line 13.
... on line 10 Form 1040A, lines 7, 8a, 9a, 10, 11b, 12b, and 13
Add lines 2, 3, and 4
```

It produces this output:

```
Subtract line_4 from line_1.
Enter the amount from line_5
on line_4 and line_8 the same?
Skip line_9 through line_12; go to line_13.
... on line_10 Form 1040A, line_7, line_8a, line_9a, line_10, line_11b, line_12b, and line_13
Add line_2, line_3, and line_4
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is your friend:

`lines.sed`:

```
#!/bin/sed -rf
s/lines? ([0-9]+)/line_\1/g
s/\b([0-9]+[a-z]?)\b/line_\1/g
```

`lines.txt`:

```
Subtract line 4 from line 1.
Enter the amount from line 5
Are the amounts on lines 4 and 8 the same?
Skip lines 9 through 12; go to line 13.
Enter the total of the amounts from Form 1040A, lines 7, 8a, 9a, 10, 11b, 12b, and 13
Add lines 2, 3, and 4
```

demo:

```
$ cat lines.txt | ./lines.sed
Subtract line_4 from line_1.
Enter the amount from line_5
Are the amounts on line_4 and line_8 the same?
Skip line_9 through line_12; go to line_13.
Enter the total of the amounts from Form 1040A, line_7, line_8a, line_9a, line_10, line_11b, line_12b, and line_13
Add line_2, line_3, and line_4
```

You can also make this into a sed one-liner if you prefer, although the file is more maintainable.